# 'Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined'

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I tried searching for this and how to fix it on StackOverflow already but couldn't find a valid answer in my situation.

I am trying to create my bot status display how many users are in each server that it's in. Say, 1 server has 5 and a 2nd one has 5. It'd add the user counts together and display "I'm watching 10 users in 2 servers" or something of the sort.

code:

```
            bot.guilds.cache.forEach((guild) => {
              guild.members.fetch().then(g => {
                  let count = 0;
                  g.members.cache.forEach((member) => { <--- error occurs here
                      count++;
                  });
                  console.log(count);
              });
            });
```

Comment: Please share more context. I realize this is specific to discord.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use property [`guild.memberCount`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/Guild?scrollTo=memberCount) for this. Just map guild collection and get summ with reduce.

```js
const totalMembers = bot.guilds.cache.map(guild => guild.memberCount).reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
    return accumulator + currentValue
}, 0)
```

Full solution

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const bot = new Discord.Client();

bot.on('ready', () => {
    setInterval(() => {
        const totalMembers = bot.guilds.cache.map(guild => guild.memberCount).reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
            return accumulator + currentValue
        }, 0)
        const totalGuilds = bot.guilds.cache.size
        bot.user.setPresence({ activity: { name: `${totalMembers} members in ${totalGuilds} servers`, type: 'WATCHING' }});
    }, 1000 * 60 * 10);
})
```

Comment: how can i filter out bots? I tried to using filter like this ".filter(member => !member.author.bot" but it always gave me "bot is undefined"

Comment: !member.user.bot

Comment: yeah my bad, that's what i meant and it said bot is undefined.

Answer (score -1):

@Str8 you would want to check g.members before accessing it's cache. The error you are getting is because g.members doesn't have members.

```js
bot.guilds.cache.forEach((guild) => {
              guild.members.fetch().then(g => {
                  let count = 0;
                  g?.members?.cache?.forEach((member) => {
                      count++;
                  });
                  console.log(count);
              });
            });
```

Also check why members are not coming in fetch call.

Comment: This does not answer the question